# How to categorise custom posts in Wordpress and show them separately

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a Wordpress build at the moment which requires a custom post type called **gallery**. I'm very new to using them. I have included the following code in my functions file:

```
// Custom Gallery post type
function create_post_type_gallery()
{
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'gallery');
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'gallery');
    register_post_type('gallery', // Register Custom Post Type
        array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __('Gallery'),
            'singular_name' => __('Gallery Item'),
            'add_new' => __('Add New'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Gallery Item'),
            'edit' => __('Edit', 'gallery'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Gallery Post'),
            'new_item' => __('New Gallery Item'),
            'view' => __('View Gallery Item'),
            'view_item' => __('View Gallery Item'),
            'search_items' => __('Search Gallery Item(s)'),
            'not_found' => __('No Gallery Items found'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Gallery item found in Trash')
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail'),
        'can_export' => true, // Allows export in Tools > Export
        'taxonomies' => array('category')
    ));
}

function create_my_taxonomies() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'gallery_category',
        'gallery',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Gallery Category',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add New Category',
                'new_item_name' => "New Gallery Type Category"
            ),
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_tagcloud' => false,
            'hierarchical' => true
        )
    );
}
```

This has given me the option inside Wordpress to make gallery posts and assign a category to that post too, however after searching high and low, I cannot find a solution to show each category in its own loop in the template.

For example, I have a category called '**abstract**' and want to just show a loop for the gallery posts only in that category.

Can someone explain how this could be done? I'm not sure if I am going about this the correct way, so please advise if I need to change my method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$args = array('post_type'=>'gallery', 'category_name' => 'abstract');
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    // no posts found
} ?>
```

Just add the arguments in wp_query object to fetch required data.
For reference or other predefined arguments visit:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Hey man, thanks a lot!!! This didn't work until I added ";" at the end of line 2. Also it needs a closing php tag. If you can update those I will mark as best answer. Cheers!

Comment: I have updated the answer, thanks for suggetion to correct mistake. If there is no further code, its okey not to add closing tag. @TomDurkin